# How to get the output of execute shell script in lua api

Tags: bash, shell, lua

I am newbie in luci and lua api. Now I have problem about remove firewall rule from luci webgui in opnewrt. I know delete the rule is using the uci command : **uci delete firewall.@rule[index]**

But I don't know the index exectly. So I use blow shell script name **index.sh** to find the index by key word.

```
uci show firewall | grep $1 | grep -oE '\[.*?\]' | sed 's/[][]//g' | head -n 1
```

Here $1 is the mac address.

My process is get the mac address from luci web and remove the firewall rule of block the
network access from the mac address I set before. To recover the network access of the mac address.

But I use the lua api of **luci.sys.exec** and **luci.util.exec** to get the output of firewall rule index that are all wrong.

My example code:

```
1.Get the mac address from luci

local del_mac = protocol.urldecode(luci.http.formvalue("deleteMac"))

2.Execute the the shell script to get the index

local ruleindex = ut.trim(tostring(luci.sys.exec("index.sh '" .. del_mac .."'"))
local uci_delete_rule = "uci delete firewall.@rule['" .. ruleindex .. "]'"
luci.sys.exec(uci_delete_rule)

or

local index = "index.sh %s" %{list_del_mac}
local rule_index = ut.trim(tostring(luci.util.exe(index)))
local uci_delete_rule = "uci delete firewall.@rule['" .. rule_index .. "]'"
luci.sys.exec(uci_delete_rule)

3.Reload the firewall rule

luci.sys.exec("uci commit firewall")
luci.sys.exec("fw3 reload")
```

Can anyone help me to reslove the problem?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this question pertain to [openWRT LuCI interface](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/luci/start) ?

Comment: @Lenna  Yes, it's related to Luci interface.

Comment: `luci.util.exec` *returns* the standard output of the command. Do you utilise the returned value?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin Yes, As the example code I post : ut.trim(tostring(luci.sys.exec("index.sh '" .. del_mac .."'"))  I get the execute output of shell script and trun it to string . But I get nothing in both luci api : luci.sys.exec and luci.util.exe

Comment: Now I use the lua api io.popen , example code is blow: local exec = io.popen("index.sh " .. list_del_mac)   local output = exec:read("*all") I get the output still wrong. It return a random number.

Comment: I doubt that the lua api can pass string variable to execute shell script.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right to me: `"index.sh %s" %{list_del_mac}`  Unless it's short for string.format in luci, that's not proper Lua.  Concatenate your command string, or actually use string.format

`"index.sh " ..list_del_mac`

or

`string.format( "index.sh %s", list_del_mac )`

also, to get the return value after execution, you need to send it to a variable

```
return_value = luci.sys.exec(uci_delete_rule)
print( return_value )
```

Comment: I use your suggestion. But I still get nothing return on console. Below is my code using your method:  local sh = string.format("index.sh %s", del_mac) local index = luci.sys.exe(sh) local console_show = "echo index = '" .. index .. "' > /dev/console" luci.sys.exec(console_show)